# How to send a parameter (id) in a $ajax http get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, get

**Scenario**

I've had a problem for 4 hours, I'm trying to send an http get request while sending the user ID as a parameter. I try a lot of examples found on the net but I still have this error on the backend side.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/getusersbyid/?userId=00c1308a-32ad-48a0-8737-d4682b2b504e 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my **JS** function code:

```
async function getUserById() {
   try {
      await $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/getusersbyid",
         data: {
            userId: "00c1308a-32ad-48a0-8737-d4682b2b504e"
         },
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }).done(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
      }).fail(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Here is my **Backend** function code using **NodeJs**:

```
getUserById: function(req, res) {
   let userId = req.body.userId;
   models.User.findOne({
      where: {
         id: userId
      },
      include: [{
         model: models.TypeUser,
         attributes: ['code', 'value']
      }]
   }).then(function(data) {
      if (data) {
         res.status(201).json({
            'status': 'success',
            'code': 201,
            'data': data
         });
      } else {
         res.status(404).json({
            'status': 'falled',
            'code': 404,
            'message': 'Unable to find one or more users'
         });
      }
   }).catch(function(err) {
      res.status(500).json({
         'status': 'falled',
         'code': 500,
         'message': 'An internal error has occurred',
         'data': err
      });
   });
}
```

[Here is my **Backend** **Error Message** image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptYIS.jpg)

Need your help and suggestions

Comment: I'm not an express user but don't you have to use `req.query` for GET parameters?

Comment: Can you share the image of what you get in the backend when you do `console.log( req )`

Comment: @palaѕн Here is the image capture of the server-side response: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptYIS.jpg

Comment: Have you tried logging `req.query` or `req.params`?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I spent all afternoon figuring it out, now you saved my life. I just changed REQ.BODY to REQ.QUERY and it's going great. Thanks @AbhishekKumawat

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, It's going very well.

Comment: @DidiersonAmuri You're welcome. Its `req.query` because you are using `GET` method. If you use `POST` method, `req.body` will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem after reading the answers from [@AbhishekKumawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7835882/abhishek-kumawat) and from [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy). So using the "**GET**" method, I should do this:

```
let userId = req.query.userId;
```

instead.

```
let userId = req.body.userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems something's going on in your backend. Have you tried using logging, for example after your "let userId = req.body.userId;" line to see if your server is receiving the userId?

```
console.log("backend received userId="+userId)
```

Comment: I did the logging, and nothing happens on the back end, the req.body and empty.

Comment: great :) remember that logging is a great way to find problems server-side and even in client-side javascript